# Send CAN Message

Tags: can-bus, obd-ii, elm327

I'm trying to use my smartphone to move my cars windows up and down. I recorded the CAN traffic two times by using AT MA. First time I just turned the ignition on. The second time I pushed the buttons for the electric windows. 
I guess the PIDs for the window are the ones which didn’t occur in my first log file…
Now I want to try this by sending the bytes back but how can this be done with the ELM 327?
This is a message I received:

400 23 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

I already tried to set the header by doing:

AT SH 400

And then I wrote the remaining bytes to the stream:

23 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

But this seems not to be the cheat…

Cheers,
Stefan

Comment: 'car' does not refer to drivable cars.  It is part of R language.  Also given your score and you have been a member for two years you should know that SO is about programming questions.

Comment: @graham.reeds: I fixed it, but at 10K you could have done that too.

Comment: Done what?  If you mean the car tag I did remove it but also commented on the question.

Comment: Sorry. I've added that while I tried to find additional tags. Seems that I saved is accidently...